# Ejecutar una tarea automáticamente en php o mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy trabajando un módulo de contratos de empleados. Ya trabajé la parte de hacer contrataciones y dar de baja a un empleado, pero son tareas que se pueden hacer manualmente.

Resulta que cuando doy de alta un empleado y dicho empleado (por ejemplo) acaba su contrato la fecha 21-10-2022, necesito que su estado de "activo" pase a un estado "inactivo" automáticamente al cumplirse el día (21-10-2022).

He estado leyendo que se puede usar un programador de tareas CRON (pero esto se podría probar si se sube a un hosting), pero de forma local ¿cómo se podría? Un programador de eventos en Mysql sí creo que se puede, pero cuando lo lleve a producción, los hosting según leí no dan accesos a este tipo de funcionalidades (no lo sé en realidad).

Answer (score 0):

el cron es una característica de cualquier Unix/linux (que puede usar tu prveedor de hosting, pero tbm podés tener en tu estacion de trabajo)

Si trabajas en windows tbm tiene su 'programador de tareas', en caso del windows 10 probá con:

https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/forum/all/windows-10-c%C3%B3mo-activar-el-programador-de/b4426fd1-fce4-4274-9202-cb1a9775fd3e

en Mac:

[https://support.apple.com/es-lamr/guide/remote-desktop/apd65c7627e/mac#:~:text=Programar%20una%20tarea&text=En%20la%20ventana%20de%20tareas,continuaci%C3%B3n%2C%20haga%20clic%20en%20Aceptar](https://support.apple.com/es-lamr/guide/remote-desktop/apd65c7627e/mac#:%7E:text=Programar%20una%20tarea&text=En%20la%20ventana%20de%20tareas,continuaci%C3%B3n%2C%20haga%20clic%20en%20Aceptar).

podés googlear según que SO uses...como resolver que se dispare una tarea.

Una vez que definís el mecanismo para iniciar una tarea (por ejmplo cada dia a las 5:am o cualquier hora ANTES que empieces tu trabajo) esa tarea o proceso debiera ser un programa PHP (tenés q tenes habilitada la opción CLI) para que recorra la tabla verificando fecha de caducidad de la contratación para cambiarle el estado)
Ojo, al ser una db MySql ese proceso podría programarse desde cualquier lenguaje de programación, no tiene xq ser exclusivamente PHP.

abrazo y suerte!!